# Matlab Code : How can I detect shapes with one or more holes in an image using structure elements and logic

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, structure, element

I have an image that contains many circular and rectangular shapes. Some of them have one or more holes. I want to detect and count the shapes that have one or more holes using structure elements and logic. how can I do this?

Comment: I could have sworn this question was asked two weeks ago, but I can't find it...

Comment: I even still got the [image](http://i.imgur.com/btPllpL.jpg)....

Comment: @knedlsepp - That was answered by Divakar.  I'll find the link and mark as duplicate.

Comment: OP - Refer to the duplicate post.  That post shows you how to do it for one object.  Simply repeat the procedure for all of your objects in your image.  Do a `bwlabel` on your image first, then run a loop that extracts out a binary mask where each element is `true` if the object belongs to the corresponding ID and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @rayryeng: Ah! I've already stumbled upon his answer two weeks ago when looking for a duplicate, but couldn't find it now. Still, there was definitely yet another one recently asked with the wording *number of holes* of blobs. I guess it might have been deleted then...

Comment: @knedlsepp - I know exactly which question you're talking about, and I even remember that image too.  I did a search for "holes", "blobs" and "number" like you did and I couldn't find anything.... and I remember Divakar writing a comment that provided the OP with his link (see duplicate).  I figured the most canonical answer was Divakar's, and so I finally marked that as the duplicate.  StackOverflow really needs to improve their search engine.... and what's more annoying are the organization of my favourites.  You can't even search those and it gets very disorganized.

Comment: @rayryeng: Did find it in my browser history. It got [deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153796/image-processing-matlab). Well, linking to Divakar's answer is the right solution anyway, but I wanted closure on this missing question. ;-)

Comment: @knedlsepp - Aha, thanks :)  Yeah I can see the question got deleted.  When you have >= 10K reputation points, you are able to see deleted posts.  As long as you have a link back to that question, StackOverflow caches it forever.