# MATLAB: Simple cellfun does not work on string vector

Tags: matlab

I constructed my vector as such:

```
v = ['asdf'; 'qwer'; 'zxcv'];
```

I just wanted to take the first 2 characters, and I wrote a simple `cellfun` like so:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) x(1:2), v, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

However, it says:

```
error: cellfun: C must be a cell array
```

How should I extract the first 2 characters of each string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `v` is **not** a cell array.  Turn it into one:

```
v = {'asdf'; 'qwer'; 'zxcv'};
```

If you can't use cell arrays, do what Divakar suggested and turn `v` into one by using [`cellstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html):

```
v = ['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv'];
v_cell = cellstr(v);
```

If you want to escape the temporary variable, supply the call with `v` directly into `cellfun`:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) x(1:2), cellstr(v), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

If you want to **un**-cell the cell array, use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
Aout = cell2mat(A);
```

---

I question the efficiency of the above though.  If you just want to extract the first two characters of your cell array **then turn it back into a character array**, why don't you simply index the first two columns of all of the rows in the original character array?  The use of `cellfun` adds unnecessary overhead when simple indexing would do the trick.  Indexing is much more readable in this instance than using `cellfun`, which adds a layer of obfuscation.

```
Aout = v(:,1:2);
```

Comment: I can't turn it into a cell array. The vector v has to stay as is. Is there another way?

Comment: @Mariska Try `v_cell = cellstr(v)` and then use `v_cell` in that `cellfun` call.

Comment: @Mariska - Then why are you using `cellfun` if you can't use a cell array?  Yes, do what Divakar said and use `cellstr`.

Comment: Then how can I output in the same format as the original v?

Comment: @Mariska - `cell2mat`.  I've edited my answer.  Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: @Mariska If you want to have that `char array` format back for the output, you don't need to mess with `cellfun`, just do `v(:,1:2)`!

Comment: @Divakar - Yes!  Another XY problem *face palm*

Comment: @Divakar - Can you provide me a link to that post you did that detects whether or not an object consists of an entire shape or a shape with holes in it?  I'm trying to mark a post as duplicate and StackOverflow's search engine sucks.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613474/distinguish-a-simply-connected-figures)?

Comment: @Divakar - This is the post I'm about to mark as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427344/matlab-code-how-can-i-detect-shapes-with-one-or-more-holes-in-an-image-using-s#comment45200580_28427344 - Is it correct that I reference your post to mark the one in question as duplicate?

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah I think that posted solution must work for this new problem too! So, go ahead!

Comment: @Divakar - Done.  Thanks!  I have favourited that post though a while ago.  I spent 5 minutes trying to find it in my favourites.... since you were here, I figured I'd ask you directly lol.

Comment: @rayryeng Do another facepalm! ;) Well `bsxfun` there too!!

Comment: Haha got me thinking on this... and this actually could be a minimal complete and verifiable example of an XY problem! :D I am tempted to favourite this post hehe!